# Can't pass an int to setMessage(String) method

Tags: java, android

Why do I get compile error in this sentense?

```
this.message.setMessage(R.string.game_over);
```

Error messsage:

```
The method setMessage(String) in the type Messages is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

I want to use string from my res which exist in string file. I know the arg is `int` but this is the way I read in sites

Comment: Because R.string.game_over is the resource id, which is an integer, for the string value you have specified in xml file.

Comment: *I want to use string from my res which exist in string file. I know the arg is int but this is the way I read in sites* looks like the tutorial you're following and/or all the sites where you encounter the code like that have not even tested the proposed code.

Answer (score 3):

The int is a resourceID. You have to get the String the ID represents:

```
this.message.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.game_over));
```

Comment: it seems good idea but it show me number (now there is no compile error..)

    `gameThread = new PingPongGame(this.getResources())`
in PingPongGame: 

`  this.res=res;
              this.message.setMessage(res.getString(R.string.game_over)); `

Comment: not error , but I see the numer and not the string in the appץ

Comment: You are using this getString method? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString(int)

Comment: The numer I see is the resurce number.. (My privious comment was wrong)

Comment: Try clean and build, restart.. all that stuff.. Sounds like this should not happen.

Comment: I try to clean..not helping

Comment: I wouldn't know then. Try getResources().getString(R.string.game_over); save it in a string, check value in log/debug and put it in the message. That's all I can think of for you to see the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The method `setMessage` expects to receive a `String`. However, you are sending it an integer.

More specifically, you are sending it the integer which is the resource key to a string. To get the string you want, you will need to do something like:

```
Context myContext = getApplicationContext();
this.message.setMessage(myContext.getString(R.string.game_over));
```

Comment: Maybe you can answer me in the comments above?

Comment: So, when you use the code I've put, what do you get on the screen, I've struggled to follow the comments above, sorry.

Comment: what is "this" in your code? I want this code in regular class extend thread